# How do I access blueprint beans from camel during bundle shutdown

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, aries

I have a blueprint bundle containing several beans referenced by some Camel routes. When I stop the bundle (directly or by asking Karaf to terminate) the BluePrint container is destroyed almost immediately.

Meanwhile the Camel DefaultShutdownStrategy will wait for my inflight exchanges to complete. At this point any attempt to resolve a bean reference from Camel will fail (as the BlueprintContainer where the beans are registered has been destroyed), and I'll get a org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException.

Is there a way to keep the BluePrint registry alive until Camel has finished shutting down?

My environment is Karaf 4.1.1/Camel 2.18.3/Java 8/Windows.

Comment: Try to set your blueprint `<bean>` to have a `depends-on` attribute on the `<camelContext>` if that is possible. Then blueprint may shutdown the bean after Camel. Also try to upgrade Camel to latest 2.18.x

Comment: Thanks Claus. I'll give it a go as soon as I get a chance